# Send a message over network using cmd to specified PC name and username?

Tags: batch-file, networking, active-directory, cmd, message

Is there any way in Windows 7 to send a message to another computer within the active directory? I know the host name and username. And if there is, can I make it to where I don't have to start anything on the computer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `msg.exe`. Try typing `msg.exe /?` at the command prompt.

```
C:\>msg.exe /?
Send a message to a user.

MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
    [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]

  username            Identifies the specified username.
  sessionname         The name of the session.
  sessionid           The ID of the session.
  @filename           Identifies a file containing a list of usernames,
                      sessionnames, and sessionids to send the message to.
  *                   Send message to all sessions on specified server.
  /SERVER:servername  server to contact (default is current).
  /TIME:seconds       Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.
  /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
  /W                  Wait for response from user, useful with /V.
  message             Message to send.  If none specified, prompts for it
                      or reads from stdin.
```

Comment: So this is at an active directory. I am a local computer administrator for the computer I am going to send the message from, but not on the remote computer. Would this still work? thanks!

Comment: I haven't really used it before, you'll have to do some research.