# I am trying to make a batch file messenger

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file messenger to communicate between just two people.

```
@echo off
color a
title MESSENGER
cls
:start
cls
title MESSENGER
echo Where do you want to go?
echo 1. Inbox
echo 2. New Message
echo Enter the number of your choice
echo ________________________________________________________________
set /p startc=Choice:
if %startc% equ 1 goto inbox
if %startc% equ 2 goto ini
if %startc% neq 1 goto bad
if %startc% neq 2 goto bad
:bad
cls
echo Sorry but that is not a choice.
pause 
goto start
:inbox
cls
set /p msgin= <\\MYPC\msg.txt
echo %msgin%
pause
goto start
:ini
cls
echo Please don't send messages longer than one line.
echo YOU CAN TYPE NOW
echo ________________________________________________________________
set /p msg= MESSAGE:
echo %msg%>\\OtherPC\msg.txt
cls
echo DELIVERING--
echo !!
timeout/t 1 /nobreak>nul
cls
echo DELIVERING--
echo !!!!
timeout/t 1 /nobreak>nul
cls
echo DELIVERING--
echo !!!!!!
timeout/t 1 /nobreak>nul
cls
echo DELIVERING--
echo !!!!!!!!
timeout/t 1 /nobreak>nul
cls
echo MESSAGE DELIVERED!
pause
goto start
```

I want it to save a file on the Other Pc.
But I can't echo to a network location.
So if anyone can help me.
And please let me know if it is possible using a simple set of commands because I have to explain the working of this to a kid.

I am running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853783/send-a-message-over-network-using-cmd-to-specified-pc-name-and-username Why the hell would you use batch for that?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Sorry I forgot to mention, I am running windows 8.1

Comment: You might be interested in using the `waitfor` command to send a signal to another computer alerting them that a message is waiting.  Then the messaging could be instant and you won't need an inbox.  Just type msg.txt when a signal is received.  `waitfor /?` in a console window for details.

Comment: Bless your heart magnus.  You're trying to send messages between Windows XP and Windows Not XP?  `net send` requires XP while `msg` requires Vista+, and I suspect not all versions.  XP can't listen for a `waitfor` signal.  You could use `wmic`, and JScript's `WshShell.SendKeys` to trigger the console to check for new messages, but that'll defeat the explaining to a kid requirement.  I'll have to ponder this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the `ECHO` to a network location.

However, it seems that you are only specifying a machine name and a file name (`\\OtherPC\msg.txt`).

You need to also include a share name. For example, your line of code:

```
echo %msg%>\\OtherPC\msg.txt
```

Should be something like this:

```
echo %msg%>\\OtherPC\Sharename\msg.txt
```

`Sharename` is an example. You will need use an actual share name on the computers you are using.

Comment: And will it not require a username and password input?

Comment: The share name is the name given to a folder that has been shared on a computer. If the user that will be running your batch file has read/write access to that share, then you should not have to supply a username or password.